# pulumi stuck at gcp.organizations.getIAMPolicy

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

We are using `pulumi` version `2.18.2` (we tried also with `1.14.1`) with GCP provider to create IAM policy on a project.

Our code is stuck and we noticed that the issue comes from the following code (minimal reproducible example), that does not complete ("*Is never displayed*" log message is never displayed) :

```js
console.log("Before operation that does not complete...");
const policyDataIAM = gcp.organizations.getIAMPolicy({
    bindings: []
});
console.log("Is never displayed");
```

`pulumi up` shows :

> Before operation that does not complete...

After 1 hour, only this log appears.

Any idea or people who can reproduce the issue would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue cause is because we were using an old version of `pulumi/gcp` package. In `package.json`, we updated it from :

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@pulumi/gcp": "^0.18.14"
}
```

to

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@pulumi/gcp": "^4.9.0"
}
```

And now it works : it is not stuck at `gcp.organizations.getIAMPolicy` operation.